# Applying jQuery Fade in or Scroll Effect to Facebook Like Newsfeed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, facebook, feed

I have a news feed that has been developed using PHP, MySQL, and jQuery. The news feed does it's job by getting new content every 5 seconds. However, this is done by a "refresh" of the complete content. I want to only ADD any new content to the news feed. I want a fade in or scroll effect to be used (jQuery) for this to occur. The items already loaded should stay on the feed and NOT reload with any new content. How can I do this?

Here are my 2 pages and code.

feed.php

```
 <body >

    <script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
      refreshNews();
    }, 5000);
    </script>




    <div id="news"></div>


    <script>

        function refreshNews()
        {
            $("#news").fadeOut().load("ajax.php", function( response, status, xhr){

                if (status == "error"){

                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/f12_database_connect.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_f12_database_connect, $f12_database_connect);
$query_newsfeed_q = "SELECT * FROM newsfeed ORDER BY pk DESC";
$newsfeed_q = mysql_query($query_newsfeed_q, $f12_database_connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_newsfeed_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsfeed_q);
$totalRows_newsfeed_q = mysql_num_rows($newsfeed_q);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>pk</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_newsfeed_q['pk']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_newsfeed_q['title']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_newsfeed_q['content']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_newsfeed_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsfeed_q)); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($newsfeed_q);
?>
```

Comment: You really should stop using the ancient `mysql_*` function and learn how to use either [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure exactly how you have this setup, but it does not seem right:

1. Create a file that only contains the php code, and this file is going to return a json object that will contain the up to date news; you will parse the object on the client side. The following is an example of what the response of this php file will look like.

**newsFeed.php**

```
<php
     $array_with_news = array('news1' => array('pk' => 'pk1', 'title' => 'title1', 'content' => 'title2'), 'news2' => array('pk' => 'pk2', 'title' => 'title2', 'content' => 'content2'));

     echo json_encode($array_with_news);
?>
```

1. The second file is going to contain both feed.php and the rest of ajax.php. When you do your ajax called for the updated news, the newly created php file will response with a json object that you will parse and set the values of the table with its up to date content.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text\javascript">

window.setInterval(function(){
  updateNews();
}, 5000);


function updateNews(){
 var scope = this;
 $.getJSON('newsFeed.php*', function(data) {
  //data will contain the news information
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
   this.addNewsRow(value);
  });

 });
}

function addNewsRow(newsData){
 //this function will add html content 
 var pk = newsData.pk, title = newsData.title, content = newsData.content;
 $('#news').append(pk + ' ' + title + ' ' + content);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="news"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not test this, but this is the overall idea of how it should work. index.php is where the user is going to be, every interval we are going to execute updateNews and this function is in charge of calling newsFeed.php through AJAX. newsFeed.php is in charge of query the database and responding with a json object that contains all the news information. Once updateNews() gets a response from newsFeed.php it will loop through the JSON object and add the content of the response to the div.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you please give me a detailed description on how to do this? I'm not too advanced in jQuery and I don't understand Json Objects.

Comment: What about when I get the data from the database? What will assign the values to?

Comment: Where does the SQL and Querying of the data come into all of this?

Comment: In the newsFeed.php, you will query the database and store the result in the array_with_news variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could always begin by stopping the abuse of `innerHTML`.

Instead you should send JSON from your server as a replay and "build" then DOM for the new items manually. To make it easier , i would suggest to, besides data about news, send another parameter: *version number*.

The flow of data goes like this:

1. you have no `version` number available in closure ( first run ):

   - send request to `ajax.php` and receive JSON
   - extract `version` number and store in local closure
   - loop through all data items, and generate news feed ( not with innerHTML )
2. value of `version` is **not** `undefined`:

   - you request data from `ajax.php?version=XXXX` and receive JSON:

     1. if JSON is empty `{}`, then there are no new feeds. Do nothing
     2. if JSON contains data , then:

        - you update `version` to the latest received from server
        - loop through all the data and add news feed items

Thats how i would do it.

Comment: I want to use the steps given in the answer initially provided in this question. It is the easiest way I know how to do this. My question is where will my SQL Query go?